# ssrs total values for one column (tablix)

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have the following tablix
[image: ssrsstart]

which needs to produce something like this:
[image: ssrsfinal]

I can populate the `Burger flipper` and `cashier` and all their values easily with row grouping. What I cannot figure out is how to sum the `Charged` column. Thoughts?

**Edit:**
I've tried adding the following to sum my charges but get an error saying I cannot nest aggregates:
`=SUM(Round((Round(Sum((((Fields!Amt_Time_Min.Value) + (Fields!Amt_Time_Hrs.Value * 60))/60)),3) * Round(Fields!ServHrRate.Value)),2))`

Comment: So middle row in the tablix is details that produce all the results and Total is the footer of rowgroup?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter correct, details in the middle grouped by rated (which doesn't fit with my example data but for my real data it's the way it needs to be) and the total is from right clicking the group and selecting add total row as i thought this was the direction i needed to head.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Total` row is the footer of row group insert into it's `Charged` cell function:

```
=SUM(Fields!Charged.value)
```

(substitute with a real dataset field). It should summarize all the values of the details row.

Comment: `time spent (hours)` is an expression based on a calculation (hrs and min are stored separately in the database, the calculation combines to the two), `rates` is based on the group and `Charged` is the `time spent` and `rates` expressions multiplied so I can't simply say `=SUM(Fields!Charged.value)`

Comment: Then include the same formula u use in details of Charged column into `=SUM( )`

Comment: that was one of the first things I tried. I get an error saying that I cannot nest aggregate functions

Comment: Can u update your post with this full formula that you tried?

Comment: That internal SUM - how does it work in the details section? Does it really produce summary of entire column?

Comment: Also, I tried that expression in my environment - it seems to work. What version of SSRS/BIDS are u using?

Comment: the sum is adding minutes and adjusted hours to minutes for each group (in the above example two groups). mine was done in vs2010 and by the error it gave me it seems pretty standard to not allow nested sums.